# Recommended friendly mouse for graphic design work

Tags: tools, hardware-recommendation

I've used a variety of mice and recently getting a lot of cramp from long hours editing in Photoshop. Please could someone recommend a mouse that will help.

Comment: Wacom Intuos.... ditch the mouse completely.

Comment: I have one at home for my MAC - brilliant product - thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try a small one. Let your hand rest on the table and move the mouse by your thumb and nameless finger. Set the mouse fast enough and be sure to have an easy to use speed switch on the mouse.

**Addendum**: If you are a competent traditional pen user, then at least do as already suggested: Get Wacom. You get an enormous accuracy and speed boost for  drawing in Photoshop. Beware cheap imitations. Their delay and unconsistency make you mad.

Comment: Yeah, I use a small wireless Logitech mouse and it works just fine for graphic design. Only thing is the receiver takes up a USB port.

Comment: nameless finger?

Comment: @PieBie It's a word by word translation of our local name. It's the  one where usually a ring is held.

Comment: Ah, the ring finger :)

Answer (score 0):

It's amazing how many designers do great work with just a regular mouse or touchpad. I prefer a trackball with scroll wheel and programmable buttons.

One main advantage of trackballs is you can hit the buttons without shifting the pointer at all.

You don't have to lift or move the mouse to operate it so it's much easier on your shoulder, wrist and hand.

Mine has 4 big programmable buttons, I've added copy, paste and scroll lock but you can assign any keyboard functions.

It's the Kensington Expert mouse, I highly recommend. You rotate ball with fingertips and left click with thumb.

Logitech has a good line of trackball mice, I've used many. Some you roll the ball with your thumb. Odd at first, I got used to it fast, but most other people won't be able to use your mouse, which can be an advantage.

I don't recommend handheld. Wireless is fine for a laptop and wired works with a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [Logitech M330](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/m330-silent-plus) silent mouse, its a new model, ok not entirely silent but about 75% more silent when clicking than a *regular* mouse. It may not sound like such a big deal, but after using this for a while I wouldn't go back to a *regular* mouse any more.

It's also quite good for design work, nothing to complain about. Using the CS Suite daily with no problems. Not doing any intense Photoshop retouching however, just basic stuff mostly, for that I'm sure a Wacom is better.

Using one of those [gel pads](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fellowes-9112101-Crystals-Mouse-Support/dp/B0012315XU) could help your cramping.